# PHP - Codeigniter - Connecting to a PostgreSQL error

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

I am new on codeigniter and connect it with postgres. when i am filling data  in my login page and press the submit button then it show the error.

Error Number:

```
ERROR: column "id" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT "id", "user_name", "user_pass" ^

SELECT "id", "user_name", "user_pass" FROM "admin" WHERE "user_name" = 'aziz' AND "user_pass" = 'aziz12' LIMIT 1

Filename: C:\wamp\www\ci_login\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 331
```

In codeigniter config->database.php file configuration is

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'postgres';
$db['default']['password'] = 'postgres';
$db['default']['database'] = 'login';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'postgre';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['port'] = 5432;
```

Comment: please check your database design , the error shows id column doesn't exit, 

table 'admin' doesn't contain 'id'

Answer (score 0):

Hi Your Query should be like this

```
SELECT id, user_name, user_pass FROM admin WHERE user_name = 'aziz' AND user_pass = 'aziz12' LIMIT 1
```

In CI use below code

```
$this->db->select("id, user_name, user_pass FROM admin");
$this->db->from("admin");
$this->db->where("user_name","aziz");
$this->db->where("user_pass","aziz12");
$this->db->limit(1);
$query = $this->db->get();
echo "<pre>";print_r($query->row_array());
```

Thanks